# looping in a folder reading files with a specific pattern...getting an error perl

Tags: perl

I have a code that is able to read two files as input and make a comparison between the two writing matching elements in the output. Let's consider the $list_file readen by my script as a fixed list used to chose elements from the $data_file. I'm trying to make this script looping in a folder and reading multiple data_files with a specific name pattern, but I'm getting an error and I'm not able to solve it.

Here is my list_file named "list.txt":

```
X1 A B
X2 C D
X3 E F
```

And my first data_file named "data_file1.txt":

```
A X1 2 5
B X1 3 7
C X2 1 4
D X2 1 5
```

And my second data_file named "data_file2.txt":

```
E X3 5 7
F X3 3 4
G X4 2 3
H X4 2 5
```

I would like to obtain an output that looks like this:

```
X1 A B 2 5 3 7
X2 C D 1 4 1 5
X3 E F 5 7 3 4
```

Both my data_files are in a folder that contains also other files, so I need to match "data" as pattern to recognize the correct inputs.

And this is my code:

```
my $list_file = "list.txt";
my $dirname = "data_directory";
my $dh;

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature 'say';  

opendir ($dh, $dirname) || die "Impossible open the $dirname!";
while (my $data_file = readdir ($dh)){
    if ("$dh/$data_file" =~ /data/){

        open my $data_fh, "<", $data_file;
        my %data;
        while (<$data_fh>) {
            chomp;
            my ($id2, $id1, @data) = split /\t/;
            $data{$id1}{$id2} = \@data;
        }

        open my $list_fh, "<", $list_file;
        LINE: while(<$list_fh>) {
            chomp;
            my ($id1, @id2s) = split /\t/;
            my $data_id1 = $data{$id1};
            defined $data_id1 or next LINE;  

            my @values = map @{ $data_id1->{$_} }, @id2s;  
            say join "\t", $id1, @id2s, @values;
        }
    }
}
closedir (DIR);
```

If I run this code I get the right result only for the first data_file. Moreover I get this error:

```
"Can't open 'data_file2.txt' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at code.pl line 23"
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In `"$dh/$data_file"`, `$dh` is not a path. Also, `open ... $data_file` will probably not point to a file as you need a more complete path like `"$dirname/$data_file"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ane '
  BEGIN{ open $I,shift or die $! }
  ($x, $y) = splice(@F,0,2);
  $h{$x}{$y} = "@F";
  END{ 
    @F=split, 
    s/$/ $h{ $F[1] }{ $F[0] } $h{ $F[2] }{ $F[0] }/, 
    print 
      while <$I>
  }
' list.txt *data*.txt
```

output

```
X1 A B 2 5 3 7
X2 C D 1 4 1 5
X3 E F 5 7 3 4
```

Comment: what to do if my data_file are hundreds?

Comment: @Gabelins check update, second argument takes all files in folder that match `*data*.txt` pattern

Comment: It's been years since I've seen anyone write such fluent awk in Perl. A salutary lesson to those of us who suffer from an instinct to verbosity -- I salute you, sir.

Comment: @AaronMiller thanks; can't make comment on awk though, as I'm not very familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what `$fils_list` is for a start

```
$ perl -cw ff.pl 
Global symbol "$fils_list" requires explicit package name at ff.pl line 22.
ff.pl had compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :-

```
open my $data_fh, "<", $data_file;
```

perhaps you need this :-

```
open my $data_fh, "<", "$dh/$data_file"
```

See the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a list of all files whose names start with `data_` and end with `.txt`, and they're guaranteed to be in a single level of the directory tree that's immediately below the script's working directory, you can cheaply obtain the list with

```
@data_files = glob('**/data_*.txt');
```

If they're in a single directory, e.g. "datapath", that's even simpler; just

```
@data_files = glob('datapath/data_*.txt');
```

In general, this is a problem you don't have to solve for yourself, because the Perl implementers have already solved it for you; for more information on how to adapt `glob()` to your specific case, try `perldoc -f glob`, which will give you all the detail you can stand. Failing that, you might look into `File::Find`, which requires a bit more effort, but offers much more flexibility in exchange; for problems `glob()` can't solve, `File::Find` should probably be the first tool you reach for.

In this case, though, assuming the following directory structure

```
list-and-data/
list-and-data/list.txt
list-and-data/data/data_1.txt
list-and-data/data/data_2.txt
list-and-data/data/et-cetera.txt
list-and-data/data/something-else.txt
```

and that you want only to pick out the data files in `data/`, you might simply:

```
sub read_file {
  my $filename = shift();
  my @data;
  open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Can't open '$filename' to read: $!\n";
  @data = <$fh>
    or die "Failed to read '$filename', or empty: $!\n";
  close $fh;

  chomp foreach @data;
  return \@data;
};

my $list_file = "list.txt";
my $dirname = "data/";
my $data_filespec = "data_*.txt";

my @list = @{ read_file($list_file) };

my %data = {};
my @files = glob("$dirname/$data_filespec");

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $basename = $file; $basename =~ s@^.*/@@;
  $data{$basename} = read_file($file);
};
```

At this point, you have the contents of `list.txt` in `@list`, and the contents of all your data files in `%data`, keyed by the file's basename (e.g. "list-and-data/data/data_1.txt" would be keyed by "data_1.txt").

This simplifies your life considerably; there's no need to bother with `opendir()` and friends, and your file-reading code is all in one place, so if you need to make any changes to how it behaves, you won't have to wander through the entire source file doing the same thing over and over.

Similarly, all your data is in one place, helpfully keyed by the filename in which it was found, so the remainder of the analysis is as simple as iterating over `keys %data`.

Comment: if I add the glob() command after opening the directory I get this error: "can't open 'GLOB(0x1198cd8)/data_file1.txt' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at code.pl line 23

Comment: @Gabelins `glob()` doesn't operate on a directory handle; you give it a path specification, and it gives you back a list of expanded paths that matched the spec. It actually works much like shell globbing, hence the name; I encourage you to peruse `perldoc -f glob` to see more about how it works and what it can do for you. In the meantime, I'll extend my question to include a brief example.